# whats the correct way to put a cite in foot and the end of the document both at the same time?

Tags: citing, biber, footer

I have to cite on the page and in a reference seciton at the same time with the same numbering.

I found many different solutions and im not sure what is the correct way to go.

this mwe sample bilds to a reference that shows the footcite with number 1 and in the reference with number 2. Thats not what i need. I nee both with the same number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibstyle=numeric,
citestyle=verbose,
sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
    title = {{Use-Case 2.0 ebook}},
    journal = {Ivar Jacobson International},
    year = {2014},
    month = {7},
    note = {[Online; accessed 24. Dec. 2018]},
    url = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}
}
@online{AlistairCockburn,
    title = {{Alistair Cockburn {\textendash} Wikipedia}},
    year = {2018},
        month = {12},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alistair_Cockburn},
    note = {[Online; accessed 25. Dec. 2018]},
}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
sometext \cite{UseCase20}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. some more text \footcite{AlistairCockburn}
Sed commodo posuere pede. Mauris ut est. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque non elit.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: falseNumberinginReference]

For those who can read German this is the document that causes this question:

[image: IBZanforderungen]

And this is a google translated english version (no guarantee that it is correct):

**Abbreviations**
In the text only abbreviations are to be used, which allows the Duden or which are colloquially familiar. Subject-related terms are either spelled out on first use and the abbreviations used below are added in brackets, or listed in alphabetical order in a glossary to be categorized according to the appendix.

**footnotes**
References and notes are in footnotes. These are separated from the text by a horizontal line. A small line spacing or a smaller font give the information the right-secondary weight. The footnotes are numbered throughout the work.
Guideline Diploma thesis valid from 2016S page 6 of 9

**representations**
Tables and figures are consecutively numbered and titled in the work. For example: Fig. 3: Organizational Chart Export Department, Tab. 8: Calculation Scheme
Tables and figures must be commented on, regardless of whether they are in the text or in the appendix. So there are no representations in the preliminary work that are not mentioned at least once in the text.
Greater representations inhibit the flow of thought. It is therefore convenient to include extensive material (e.g., full-page tables) in an appendix (see below)

**bibliography**
The bibliography gives information on the literature used. All literature used in the work and all information material processed / consulted is listed alphabetically according to the author name or the name of the newspaper / trade journal, for example in the case of official publications after the name of the office or the title of the decree (leaflet, directive, regulations, ordinance etc .).

edit: work in progress:

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
style=numeric,
autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
    title = {{Use-Case 2.0 ebook}},
    journal = {Ivar Jacobson International},
    year = {2014},
    month = {7},
    note = {[Online; accessed 24. Dec. 2018]},
    url = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}
}
@online{AlistairCockburn,
    title = {{Alistair Cockburn {\textendash} Wikipedia}},
    year = {2018},
        month = {12},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alistair_Cockburn},
    note = {[Online; accessed 25. Dec. 2018]},
}@book{Cockburn2003,
    author = {Cockburn, Alistair},
    title = {{Use Cases effektiv erstellen}},
    year = {2003},
    isbn = {978-382661344-9},
    publisher = {REDLINE},
    url = {https://www.amazon.de/Cases-effektiv-erstellen-Alistair-Cockburn/dp/3826613449}
}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{footcite UseCase20:
\footcite{UseCase20}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, 
\textcolor{red}{footcite UseCase20:
\footcite{UseCase20} }
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et 
\textcolor{red}{textcite Cockburn2003:
\textcite{Cockburn2003} }
et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. some more 
\textcolor{red}{footcite AlistairCockburn:
\footcite{AlistairCockburn}}
Sed commodo 
\textcolor{red}{smartcite AlistairCockburn:
\smartcite{AlistairCockburn}} 
pede. Mauris ut est. Ut quis purus. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\textcolor{red}{supercite AlistairCockburn:
\supercite{AlistairCockburn}} Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque non elit.
et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
\textcolor{red}{autocite AlistairCockburn:
\autocite{AlistairCockburn}} Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers]

Comment: A numbered bibliography and footnotes? Who came up with something this silly? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: well, i am writing a thesis and this is a requirement given by the inspectors. I agree with you fully.

Comment: How *exactly* is the style supposed to work? How do you cite your sources (all in text, all in footnotes, some here, some there)? How should the footnote citations look like? What happens if you cite the same source multiple times on the same page? What happens if you cite a source you've cited before again on a new page? What happens if you cite two sources you've cited before again on a new page in different order? In your example the footnote number is in no way tied to the number in the bibliography.

Comment: @Johannes_B i could be a  nonsense, but this  sounds as rather an opinion than objective statement. As a PhD thesis advisor or referee, I find this very convenient.

Comment: @moewe thanks for compleeting the questionaries. I indeed forgot to tell what should hapen if i re-cite a cite and maybe in different order. 
What i need is that a cite apears in the footnote and in the reference. If i re-cite it needs to get the same number as it got in the first footcite and then in the reference it should apear only once with that same number as in both footcites.
Does this description clear my needs fully?

Comment: What should happen if you cite say reference 3 and 1 (i.e. the references that have been assigned the number 3 and 1, respectively, before) on a new page in that order. In what order should the footnotes appear. What should happen if you use normal footnotes in between? Does a work that you cite twice on the same page appear twice in the footnotes?

Comment: The order of footcites is not relevant to me, i don't mater. What is necassary is that the number is the same. Now indeed, i understand that this may interfer with footnotes and i do not know hot to handle that. Maybe its possible to change footnotes counter to Letters or Romannumbers or something like that. I do not need to write many footnotes so acualy i can maybe live totaly without. The case of second cite on same page should result in the same superscript number as the first one but only once been footcited and referenced.

Comment: Nothing I read in these instructions (I speak German, so I read the original) suggests to me that you have to re-use footnote numbers or that there should even be (footnote/citation) numbers in the bibliography. In particular there is no requirement to always use the same footnote number for the same work. It would probably go against the guidelines to decouple citations and normal footnotes ('Quellenangaben und Anmerkungen werden in Fussnoten gesetzt').

Comment: As I interpret the guidelines you should be good with `style=authoryear`, `autocite=footnote` and `\autocite`. Unless you are specifically asked to use implement the more complicated scheme you seem to think about I would just leve it be. There are some quite challenging TeXnical hurdles to overcome if one wants to implement a solution where there is only one 'cite-footnote' per work even if it is cited multiple times on a page. To make that usable the 'cite-footnotes' would probably have to be decoupled from real footnotes (more work) and would have to be sorted.

Comment: I found by luck something that can do both. Maybe you can help me work it out. I changed my style=numbered and autocite=footnote and let it run only once that produces the numbers i wold like to see. But with a pagereference number in front. Maybe its possible to get both. like in a row: [pagerefnumber]-[referencenumber]-[verbose reverence]. I will add a sample above. Is that number unreachable?

Comment: If by *pagerefnumber* you mean the footnote number it should be possible to get 'footnote number - reference number - verbose reference' in the footnotes. But I can't see how that would be more useful than say 'footnote number - verbose reference' and a simple author-year bibliography without reference numbers. In the new scheme the reference numbers are superfluous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88195/discussion-between-novski-and-moewe).

Comment: [tag:cross-referencing] is not the right tag concerning citing bibliographies etc.